# Can not determine scale of x-axis of attached graph

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions

I am trying to digitize the data from the graph in [this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZHF7.jpg).

I thought the $x$-axis was in $\log_{10}$ scale but after trying to digitize this way the points seemed off. I also tried digitizing in $\log_2$ but again failed.

Can anyone help to determine what scale the $x$-axis is in?

Comment: It looks to me like a log scale, but the tick mark for $1$ is misplaced. For example, the distance from $2$ to $4$ and the distance from $4$ to $8$ look the same, as do the distances from $2$ to $5$ and $5$ to $10$. But $2\to 4$ and $1\to 2$ are not the same.

Comment: Do you have an equation that relates the loss coefficient to $N/R_1$? If so it should be obvious from that.

Comment: I checked the book I am working from and found no equation. rogerl, that might be the case. I'll look into that for now.